# Regular expression query to pull out last piece of matching data

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a specific RegEx question, simply because I'm wracking my brain trying to isolate one item, rather than multiple.

Here is my text I am searching:

```
"{\"1430156203913\"=>\"ABC\", \"1430156218698\"=>\"DEF\", \"1430156219763\"=>\"GHI\", \"1430156553620\"=>\"JKL", \"1430156793764\"=>\"MNO\", \"1430156799454\"=>\"PQR\"}"
```

What I would like to do is capture the key associated with `ABC` as well as the key associated with `GHI`

The first is easy enough, and I'm capturing it with this RegEx:
`/\d.*ABC/` maps to: `"1430156203913\"=>\"ABC`.
Then, I'd just use `/\d/` to pull out the **1430156203913** key that I'm looking for.

The second is what I'm having difficulty with.

This does not work:
`/\d.*GHI/` maps to the start of the first digit to my final string (GHI) ->
`1430156203913\"=>\"ABC\", \"1430156218698\"=>\"DEF\", \"1430156219763\"=>\"GHI`

**Question:**
How can I edit this second Regex to just capture **1430156219763**?

Comment: If you trust the source, you can `eval(s).invert['GHI']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture all the keys and values, use **[String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan)**.

```
pairs = s.scan /"(\d+)"=>"([[:upper:]]+)"/
# [["1430156203913", "ABC"],
#  ["1430156218698", "DEF"],
#  ["1430156219763", "GHI"],
#  ["1430156553620", "JKL"],
#  ["1430156793764", "MNO"],
#  ["1430156799454", "PQR"]]
```

Then to get any k/v pair you want, hashify and find them.

```
Hash[pairs].invert.values_at('ABC', 'DEF')
# ["1430156203913", "1430156218698"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\d[^,]*GHI
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yW3oJ9/3

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to capture only the key

```
\b\d+\b(?=\\"=>\\"GHI)
```

check this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW3oJ9/4)

Notice I've added `\b` around `d+` just for a better perfromance

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could do that:

```
def extract(str, key)
  r = /
      (?<=\")   # match \" in a positive lookbehind
      \d+       # match one or more digits
      (?=       # begin a positive lookahead
        \"=>\"  # match \"=>\"
        #{key}  # match value of key
        \"      # match \" 
      )         # end positive lookahead
      /x

  str[r]
end

extract str, "ABC" #=> "1430156203913" 
extract str, "GHI" #=> "1430156219763"
```